# Tree filter: how to remove all but one directory?

Tags: git

Here's what I've tried, but the result is bizarre / unexpected:

```sh
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter \
'for f in $(ls); do if [ "$f" != "deploy" ]; \
then rm -rf "./$f"; fi done; mv "./deploy/philips/*" .; \
rm -rf "./deploy"' --prune-empty HEAD
```

formatted for readability. In reality this is a single line.

What happens is that `mv` fails because there are some files left, which the previous loop didn't remove. The action completes "successfully" processing all commits, but the effect is that what then remains in the root directory isn't filtered / only some small percent of it.

So, I have two questions:

- Isn't there an easier way to purge all but a single directory from a particular branch?
- If `filter-branch` is the way to go, can I maybe stack multiple filters? It seems like it executes the filter in random order. Is that true?

PS. If I can simplify it while sacrificing the commit history - this is an acceptable solution.

Also tried something like this:

```
$ git banch
  master
  preliminary
* release-0.6.3

$ git checkout release-0.6.3 master/deploy/philips
```

Also tried variations like `master:/deploy/philips`, `master:deploy/philips`, `/deploy/philips`, `deploy/philips` and `master -- deploy/philips` - I'm still no closer to the goal. :(

**EDIT:**

Please never mind this question. I'm an idiot! The deploy directory was ignored / nonexistent in master! this why I couldn't check it out.

Comment: I suspect what you really want is `--subdirectory-filter`, not `--tree-filter`...

Comment: @twalberg that well may be true... but I will have an answer for that Sunday morning. Thanks for suggesting it though!

Answer (score 3):

This is actually really easy using `git subtree`. Just run this (for every branch):

```
git branch newmaster `git subtree split -P deploy/philips`
```

Now you should have a new branch `newmaster` that contains the history you want. Check that, delete the old `master`, rename and you are done.

---

If you don’t have `git subtree` in your git, you can read its docu here: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt and to install it, just download this file and put it in your `git-core` folder (in cygwin that’s `…\cygwin\lib\git-core`):

https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh

Comment: `git subtree is not a git command` :( What version is that? `git --help subtree` says it doesn't exist either... (This is Git installed through Cygwin, version 1.7.9.

Comment: Oh... well, thanks than, no, no compiling on Cygwin. I want this done this week, preferably today :( But thanks for the effort!

Comment: You don't need to compile `git subtree`, it's a single shell script that you can just copy into place. +1, `subtree` is a great tool.

Comment: Extended my answer with install tip.